# How can I get RabbitMQ Logs programatically?

Tags: rabbitmq, rabbitmqctl

I wants to track which message is delivered or expired. How can i get it programatically ?

Help! if anyone knows about it.

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 0):

In order to know if the message is delivered, you can use [`mandatory`](https://www.rabbitmq.com/amqp-0-9-1-reference.html#basic.publish.mandatory) flag, then handle the result using [`basic.return`](http://www.rabbitmq.com/amqp-0-9-1-quickref.html#basic.return)

To know if a message is expired you can use [`dead letter exchange`](https://www.rabbitmq.com/dlx.html):

> Dead Letter Exchanges
>
> Messages from a queue can be 'dead-lettered'; that is, republished to
>   another exchange when any of the following events occur:
>
> The message is rejected (basic.reject or  basic.nack) with
>   requeue=false, The TTL for the message expires; or The queue length
>   limit is exceeded.

Comment: Actually I'm pushing some messages in RabbitMQ queue and now I wants that which all are delivered and expired.

Comment: I answered,  use mandatory for delivered and dead letter for expired.